# Why does Tomcat8's template for AWSElastic Beanstalk runs with httpd

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create an application using AWS beanstalk using the Tomcat8/Java8 template. I'm just wondering why does the template includes Apache HTTPd as a proxy in front Tomcat8. I don't see any stuff in httpd's configuration that can help Tomcat on anything.

elasticbeanstalk.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

elasticbeanstalk_log.conf

```
LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" eb_access_log_format
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log eb_access_log_format
```

healthd.conf

```
LogFormat "%{%s}t\"%U\"%s\"%D\"%D\"%{X-Forwarded-For}i" healthd
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/healthd/application.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H 3600" healthd
```

notrace.conf

```
# This directive overrides the behavior of TRACE for both the core server and
# mod_proxy. The default TraceEnable on permits TRACE requests per RFC 2616,
# which disallows any request body to accompany the request. TraceEnable off
# causes the core server and mod_proxy to return a 405 (Method not allowed)
# error to the client.
TraceEnable off
```

welcome.conf

```
# 
# This configuration file enables the default "Welcome"
# page if there is no default index page present for
# the root URL.  To disable the Welcome page, comment
# out all the lines below.
#
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: TLS performance is better with httpd/OpenSSL than it is with Tomcat/JSSE. Maybe that could be it? Why not ask AWS directly?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz - but in this case, SSL termination happens on ELB. Yes, I'll ask AWS as well.

Comment: *shrug* Maybe they just want to give you some configuration options, since ELB has virtually *zero* configuration options.